# Bash array: Unexpected Syntax error

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, syntax

I am writing this simple bash script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

array=( /home/abc/Downloads/something.bat /home/abc/Downloads/smb.conf )
echo ${array[@]}
```

I expected it to print all the names of the files in the array. But I get this error instead:

```
test.sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

If I change the declaration of array to

```
array = {/home/abc/Downloads/something.bat /home/abc/Downloads/smb.conf}
```

this error goes away but I still have new errors

```
test.sh: 3: array: not found
test.sh: 4: Bad substitution
```

How can I resolve this issue? This is my first time in shell programming so I am unable to fix the issues myself.

RESOLVED:

I was executing it as sh test.sh but I forgot I had to execute it as **bash test.sh**

Comment: That's not an associative array. It's a normal, numerically indexed array.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Oh Ok. I will edit it

Comment: @user1357576: Post the solution as an answer and mark it accepted, don't edit it into the question. Also, don't edit the title to resolve it, the website will mark the question as solved when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Variable assignments can't have a space around the `=` sign:

```
array=( /a/b/  /c/d )
     ^--no spaces
```

---

are you sure?

```
marc@panic:~$ array =(a b)      
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
marc@panic:~$ array= (a b)  
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
marc@panic:~$ array = (a b)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
marc@panic:~$ array=(a b)  
marc@panic:~$ echo ${array[1]}
b
```

Comment: No luck. I have removed the space still gives me the syntax error

Comment: interestingly when I execute it directly on the terminal, it works. But when I use the same thing in a file, it doesn't!

Comment: @user1357576: works fine here when I put the above into a file. Of course, the syntax error lines kill the script, but if it's just the final space-less assignment, it works fine.

Comment: I know what I did wrong. I was executing it as sh test.sh and then it was throwing the error. When I executed it as ./test.sh it worked fine!

Comment: Ah yes, sh is not alway 'sh'. On ubuntu 12.04, it's actually an alias for the 'dash' shell.

Answer (score 3):

Pointer: Spaces are important with variable assignment in BASH. Don't use them **before** or **after** the equal sign.

Comment: I understand that> I executed the very same commands directly on the terminal and it worked. BUT the same commands I put in test.sh and execute, they throw the error..Would you know why?

Comment: @user1357576 From your comment above, it appears that you've learned the difference between `sh` and `bash`. `sh` is not guaranteed to be `bash` in some environments. In fact, `sh` is often linked to purely POSIX shells such as `dash`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a DOS editor to create your script?

Bash etc shells, don't like CRLF pairs, just LF (or `\r\n` chars VS just plain `\n` char).

Put your script thru this test

```
cat -vet myScript.sh
```

Do you see '^M' chars at the end of lines? If so that is a dos file.

See if your system has dos2unix then use it like

```
dos2unix myScript.sh
```

Also, as several people have commented on it, please edit your original question to eliminate the spaces around your `=` signs in the assignments to `array`.

I hope this helps.