# How to use arrays in bash script in Debian Jessie?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

When I try to execute the following

```
#!/bin/sh

folders=("/usr/include")
for i in ${folders[@]}; do
        echo ${i}
done
exit 0
```

I get `test.sh: 3: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`. I also tried using `#!/bin/bash` but it didn't work neither. I tried this on Debian Jessie in a script and it produced the above mentioned error. The same script runs fine on Ubuntu 14.04.

Additionally I tried

```
# foo=(/usr/include); echo $foo
/usr/include
```

which worked well.
I also checked it for non-printable characters with `cat -e test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh$
$
folders=("/usr/include")$
for i in ${folders[@]}; do$
    echo ${i}$
done$
exit 0$
```

**Edit**

I executed the script as `sh ./test.sh`

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not Bash and has no arrays; you have to use `/bin/bash`, which, as I see just now, you say you did... hmmmm.

Comment: How do you call the script?

Comment: I used ```sh ./test.sh```. I just used ```chmod +x test.sh && ./test.sh``` and it seems to work with ```#!/bin/bash```.

Comment: Yep, `sh ./test.sh` will run it with `dash`, which is more strictly POSIX than bash.  See [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).  Separately, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499486/how-to-mark-an-array-in-posix-sh) has some thoughts about arrays in POSIX shells.

Comment: Yes - if you call it `sh ./test.sh`, it doesn't matter what you have in the hashbang line. It would also work with `bash ./test.sh`, no matter what's in the hashbang line.

Comment: BenjaminW. cxw is one of you going to post it as an answer. I added how I called the script initially to the question.

Comment: I'm actually fairly sure it's a duplicate, let me check.

Comment: [Bash array: Unexpected Syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026192/bash-array-unexpected-syntax-error) has the exact same problem, but no good specific answer (and it's closed as "too localized").

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`, you should use `declare -a` :

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a folders=("/usr/include");
for i in ${folders[@]}; do
  echo ${i}
done
exit 0
```

Comment: While this answer might not be wrong, the problem was solved using the proper calling convention ```bash ./test.sh```. I guess the problem would remain the same if I called your script with ```sh ./test.sh```.

Comment: Sure, you're right, this syntax is not valid for `sh`, but the OP question was for `bash`. And yes, sorry, I didn't noticed the problem was already solved.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, it was called with `sh`...

Comment: You can use `declare -a` to declare an array, but it is not necessary. Using the array assignment syntax `a=(...)` automatically sets the array attribute on a name.